How to pass F# function to RProvider
I am trying to learn how to use RProvider by using an ode solver from R via the deSolve package.
The problem is that I want to write the right hand side function in F# and pass that to the R ode fucntion as this is what I intend to do with real code.
The example I want to use is below from the deSolve package documentation but instead of having the LVmod function in R, I want it in F# to pass to the ode function.
Example1: Predator-Prey Lotka-Volterra model (with logistic prey)
LVmod <- function(Time, State, Pars) {
    with(as.list(c(State, Pars)), {
        Ingestion    <- rIng  * Prey * Predator
        GrowthPrey   <- rGrow * Prey * (1 - Prey/K)
        MortPredator <- rMort * Predator
        dPrey        <- GrowthPrey - Ingestion
        dPredator    <- Ingestion * assEff - MortPredator
        return(list(c(dPrey, dPredator)))
    })
}
pars  <- c(rIng   = 0.2,    # /day, rate of ingestion
rGrow  = 1.0,    # /day, growth rate of prey
rMort  = 0.2 ,   # /day, mortality rate of predator
assEff = 0.5,    # -, assimilation efficiency
K      = 10)     # mmol/m3, carrying capacity
yini  <- c(Prey = 1, Predator = 2)
times <- seq(0, 200, by = 1)
out   <- ode(yini, times, LVmod, pars)
summary(out)
plot(out)


You can try to write your model in F# and then a wrapper in C or Fortran to make it callable from R and deSolve. Then follow the deSolve documentation how to include models written in Fortran and C.

Thanks. The problem with that is I then have to call it back again in F#, which will affect performance since the real code has many equations and has to be run for a long period. Plus, that is a lot of indirection already.

I agree, and I wonder why to implement a model in F#. Dotnet and the GNU compilers are from different worlds. On the other hand, it is very easy to write C od Fortran code for the R/deSolve interface. One needs only the equations for the derivatives, while data handling, plotting and simulation control is done in R. A good alternative are for example code generators like packages odin or rodeo. BTW, calling between deSolve and a compiled code does not affect performance.
